# Mapreduce program with Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to run a mapreduce program written in scala. I have included scala-library in the classpath. While running the program my program throws following error.

> $hadoop jar ~/HadoopScala.jar com.learning.spark.WordCount
>   /input/wordcountinput.csv /output -libjars
>   ~/lib/org.scala-lang.scala-library_2.12.2.v20170412-161608-VFINAL-21d12e9.jar
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   scala/Predef$     at
>   com.learning.spark.WordCount$.main(WordCount.scala:52)    at
>   com.learning.spark.WordCount.main(WordCount.scala)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:234)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Predef$   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

scala.Predef$ is available in scala-library. What could be causing this error.

Comment: How did you generate the jar file?

Comment: I think libjars needs to be HDFS files, by the way.

Comment: Does that provide you with the option to make a "uber jar"? If so, you don't need to pass the libjars

Comment: I am creating the jar via scala-ide export project feature

Comment: Please look into a way to generate an "uber jar". I do this with Maven, so I don't know what your ide provides

Comment: Thanks,  uber jar solution works. I am still not able to understand why libjars  option does not work.

Comment: Because all map and reduce containers in the cluster need access to that scala library, which you've only specified for your local path on the current machine

Comment: Makes sense now. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are not running a mapreduce job but a Spark job.

If you are submitting this spark job to yarn you should user `spark-submit`.

In any case you would want to build a fat jar ( a.k.a. uber jar).

When you are using SBT, try `sbt assembely`

Comment: I am submitting a mapreduce job directly to hdfs. I am not using Yarn.

Comment: @pawinder `hadoop jar` uses YARN. HDFS is only a filesystem. It doesn't run code

Comment: i have only started dfs by executing start-dfs.sh. The list of java processes  does not include ResourceManager either. As I understand hdfs can execute mapreduce code on a cluster without yarn.

Comment: you are running your application in local mode. In other words, its your "local" machine (whatever it may be, laptop, node, vm, ...). This local application is connecting to hdfs. But please do be aware that HDFS is just a filesystem, nothing more and nothing less. It's not running your code, your code is interfacing its apis.